# 1с запрос в sql базу(Внешний источник данных)

Tags: 1с

Как в из 1с отправить запрос во внешний источник данных, но с запросом update и where
Insert я делаю так, как ниже, а как в подобном стиле сделать update запрос?

```
 Процедура Записи()
КодЯзыкаПечать ="uk";
СведенияОПоставщике     = БухгалтерскийУчетПереопределяемый.СведенияОЮрФизЛице(Объект.ОтправительПолучатель, ,,,КодЯзыкаПечать);
УстановитьПривилегированныйРежим(Истина);   
ПараметрыСоединения = ВнешниеИсточникиДанных.test.ПолучитьОбщиеПараметрыСоединения();

ПараметрыСоединения.АутентификацияСтандартная = Истина;
ПараметрыСоединения.ИмяПользователя = "";
ПараметрыСоединения.Пароль = "";
ПараметрыСоединения.СтрокаСоединения = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.2 Unicode Driver}; SERVER=; PORT=; DATABASE=;";
ПараметрыСоединения.СУБД = "MySQL";

ВнешниеИсточникиДанных.test.УстановитьОбщиеПараметрыСоединения(ПараметрыСоединения);
ВнешниеИсточникиДанных.test.УстановитьПараметрыСоединенияПользователя(ИмяПользователя(), ПараметрыСоединения);
ВнешниеИсточникиДанных.test.УстановитьПараметрыСоединенияСеанса(ПараметрыСоединения);
ВнешниеИсточникиДанных.test.УстановитьСоединение();

НаборЗаписиВоВнешнемИсточнике = ВнешниеИсточникиДанных.test.Таблицы.car.СоздатьОбъект();
НаборЗаписиВоВнешнемИсточнике.barcode = Объект.Штрихкод;    
НаборЗаписиВоВнешнемИсточнике.Записать();
```

КонецПроцедуры

А хочу выполнить запрос что-то типо
UPDATE car SET netto = "инфа из 1с" WHERE barcode = "инфа из 1с";
подскажите как примерно это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно вот так должно быть  в вашем случае

```
Автомобили = ВнешниеИсточникиДанных.test.Таблицы.car;
АвтомобильСсылка = Автомобили.НайтиПоПолю("barcode", "инфа из 1с");
Если АвтомобильСсылка <> Автомобили.ПустаяСсылка() И АвтомобильСсылка <> 
Неопределено Тогда
АвтомобильОбъект = АвтомобильСсылка.ПолучитьОбъект();
АвтомобильОбъект.netto = "инфа из 1с";
АвтомобильОбъект.Записать();
КонецЕсли;
```

вот тут возможно что то для себя найдете: https://infostart.ru/1c/articles/612354/

Comment: спасибо. то что нужно